# Classic ASP ServerXMLHttp POST to ASP.NET No Longer Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, iis-8, windows-server-2012

We recently moved from Server 2003 to Server 2012 and this no longer works.

I'm sending XML via a ServerXMLHttp call to a ASP.NET script

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

objXML.setTimeouts tResolve, tConnect, tSend, tReceive 
objXML.open "POST", url, false
objXML.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

objXML.send(cxmlText)
```

Target

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Request.ContentEncoding);
    string xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Web.Config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=SOMETOKENVALUE"/>
  </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

xmlData is empty
Request.TotalBytes returns 0
Request.RequestType returns POST

I have confirmed there is data in the request also I have tried different values for the request header like text/plain, text/xml, and the app/form which as has worked for years. I feel liked i've looked at every option available in IIS.

ANY idea on why you think there is no data, PLEASE let me know. Thank you.

Comment: How does the source gets the cxmlText? Is it a .vbs file or?

Comment: Probably a firewall or proxy issue, can't see any reason for that to happen.

Comment: Hi, We are facing the same issue. Any solution till now if any one found please share.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change create object from `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` to `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0`

Also ensure there is no `on error resume next` that hides the real error.

Comment: There is no On Error on the page and I have tried the 6.0 version. I don't know if it's code related at this point.

Comment: I would try to use fiddler to debug the query, might be the other end not responding properly, or a firewall issue

Comment: Hi, We are facing the same issue. Any solution till now if any one found please share.

Comment: use somthing more modern, like HttpClient i .net, or invoke-webrequest in powershell